# How to insert data into MySQL database using Asp.net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am trying to insert data into MYSQL database using Asp.Net but I am getting the following error message: Failed to connect to the database due to System.InvalidOperationsException.The connection must be valid and open.
Here is what I am doing:

```
protected void SU_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString = @"Data Source=mno; Database=xyz; User ID=abc; Password=abc";
            using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    string insertData = "insert into signup_table(firstname,surname,mobile_number,email_address,password," +
                                        "confirm_password) values (@F_Name, @S_Name, @M_Number, @E_Address, @Password, @C_Password)";
                    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(insertData, connection);

                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@F_Name",FN_TextBox.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@S_Name", SN_TextBox.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@M_Number", MN_TextBox.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@E_Address", EA_TextBox.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", P_TextBox.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C_Password", CP_TextBox.Text);
                    int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    connection.Open();
                    MessageBox.Show("Connected to database");
                    MessageBox.Show("Data inserted successfully");
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Failed to connect to database due to" + ex.ToString());
                    MessageBox.Show("Failed to insert data due to" + ex.ToString());
                }

            }
        }
```

Please suggest something. Thanks in advance... :)

Comment: How can you execute a query without opening the connection first? it's like getting inside the house without opening door.

Comment: Already corrected. Thanks though .. :)

Comment: I'm just curious, what was your thought process when you got this error? The error clearly says the connection needs to be open, and the error is thrown before your line to open the connection.

Comment: I never realized it probably because I am working from last 8 hours. Moreover, I am new to web development. I am good at Android programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to open your connection before you execute the query.

```
    connection.Open();
    int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

also dont forget to close your connecion after you finished.

Comment: Thak you very much it worked. What a silly mistake that was. And I created my connection with a using statement. This ensures that the connection object will always be disposed of come what may. This also means that I do not specifically need to close the connection.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
 int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
 connection.Open();
```

to this

```
  connection.Open();
  int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```